# Helping generating random numbers for simple math problems

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to write some simple code that will generate 40 math problems. The goal would be for the user to input a number in form field that indicates the highest possible sum for any of the problems (e.g., only generate problems where the two numbers add up to 10 or less). After a click to generate the problems, there would be random numbers generated to create the 40 math problems. The trick is that the two numbers must not add up to more than what was inputted in the beginning.

I can generate a random number, but I can't generate different ones without some horribly written code and I can't figure out how to set the logic so the problems match the level (i.e., highest possible sum) inputted by the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Someone asked for what I have so for, which isn't much. Just enough to badly generate two random numbers:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("number")
x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

var x=document.getElementById("number2")
x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
}
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span2"></div>
  <div class="span2">
  <div id="number" style="display:inline"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
  <div class="span2">
  <div id="number2" style="display:inline"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far? Explain what didn't work, how did you attempt to solve it, and post a live demo to reproduce the particular issue you have.

Comment: Like I said, no idea how to do this, as I'm pretty much completely new to this. See edit to my comment above.

Comment: I suggest this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: @minopret I've seen this page a number of times during all my searches and unfortunately it doesn't help that much. I can't quite figure out how to even display the random number that are generated within the right divs. This also doesn't help with the logic around constraining to certain sums.

Comment: Do you *need* to build it your self or would an existing service such as http://www.mathfactcafe.com/build/ be of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be sufficient (or at least a step in the right direction):

```
function generateRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max)+1);
}

var questionIDs = [],
    quantity = 40,
    maxValueOfSum = 10,
    q=0, 
    i=0;

while(q<quantity && i<100){
    var answer = generateRandom(maxValueOfSum),
        A = generateRandom(answer),
        B = answer - A,
        id = ''+A+''+B;// < a string id for adding to our array of used questions
    if(questionIDs.indexOf(id) == -1){// if this question does not already exist
        questionIDs.push(id);//add the id to the list
        q++;//increment question count
        document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML+='<div>Q'+q+': '+A+' + '+B+' = ______</div>';//append some HTML
    }
    i++;//increment the loop counter so it doesnt continue forever in cases where it isnt possible to get [quantity] unique questions.
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LjfyF/

Answer (score 0):

This should help with making multiple problems and with your constraint that the sum is no more than a particular highest allowable sum:

```
function myFunction(highest, i) {
    // The sum of two integers A and B, neither one negative,
    // is less than or equal to "highest".
    // Fill two elements, example IDs: numberA1 and numberB1 when i == 1.
    var x=document.getElementById("numberA" + i)
    n=Math.floor(Math.random()*(highest+1));
    x.innerHTML=n
    var x=document.getElementById("numberB" + i)
    x.innerHTML=Math.floor(Math.random()*(highest + 1 - n));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to do this:

```
function getRand(max) {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * max)+1);
}

limit=40;               // limit of the 2 numbers you want to add
answer=getRand(limit);  // get a random value for the answer
num1=getRand(answer);   // get one random number: 0 to answer
num2= answer - num1;    // calc the other number

alert("What is "+num1+" + "+num2+" ?" );
```

Comment: If the OP doesn't know how to write code to solve his problem, I doubt he is able to identify code that solves his problem. Please **explain** your solution.

Comment: You never use `maxtot` and all your variables are global... And your total is always `limit`...